# Android Sax Xml Parser attributes

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I'm using SAX for parsing the xml file and i can't get the value of "y"

here is the xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type= "text/html" ?>
<Chart1 count="3">
            <Sales_x0020_Amount Label="Sales Amount">
               <Chart1_CategoryGroup_Collection>
                  <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="URC 1">
                     <Value Y="30434929.1" />
                     <name>keeevin</name>
                  </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                  <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="URC 2">
                     <Value Y="39757503.83" />
                     <name>kevin2</name>
                  </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
                  <Chart1_CategoryGroup Label="URC 3">
                     <Value Y="19611069.73" />
                     <name>kevin</name>
                  </Chart1_CategoryGroup>
               </Chart1_CategoryGroup_Collection>
            </Sales_x0020_Amount>
</Chart1>
```

i can get the attribute "name" value but not the "y" value.

part of the code for getting the values..

```
Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);
map.put("Name", "Name:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "name"));
map.put("Y", "Y Coord:" + XMLfunctions.getValue(ee, "y"));
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
i have set a breakpoint here, it wont go through here.

```
static class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes atts)  {
        // Get the number of attribute
        int length = atts.getLength();

    // Process each attribute
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        // Get names and values for each attribute
        String name = atts.getQName(i);
        String value = atts.getValue(i);
        if(qName == "Value"){
             y = atts.getValue(i);
        }
        String nsUri = atts.getURI(i);
        String lName = atts.getLocalName(i);
    }
}
```

}

Solved it using this one:

```
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

            elementOn = true;

    if (localName.equals("Chart"))
            {
                data = new XMLGettersSetters();
            }
            if (qName.equals("Value")) {
                String attributeValue = attributes.getValue(0);
                data.setValue(attributeValue);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in startElement method in your Handler(extended DefaultHandler) write

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("Value")) {
                 map.put("Y", "Y Coord:" + attributes.getValue(0));
            }
    }
```

Comment: may you explain the parameters?

Comment: qName -tag name (in this line  <Value Y="39757503.83" /> qName=Value)
attributes - atributes array, elements start from index 0 (in this line  <Value Y="39757503.83" /> this call attributes.getValue(0) return (value of Y attribute) 39757503.83)

Comment: but what about the other parameter? what values should i pass?

Comment: See in java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html

Comment: thanks. i also found this [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/sax/get-element-attributes-in-sax-xml-parsing/) . how do you implement this if i will load a hosted xml, not a local one?

Comment: is this implementable in android? or is there another way?

Comment: saxPareser.parse(URL,Handler);

use this method public void parse (String uri, DefaultHandler dh) 


Parse the content described by the giving Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) as XML using the specified DefaultHandler.

Comment: can you look at the edit code above, it does not go to the MyHandler class. what do you think is the problem?

Comment: i have solved this

 if (localName.equals("Chart1"))
  {
   data = new XMLGettersSetters();
  }
  if (qName.equals("Value")) {
   String attributeValue = attributes.getValue(0);
   data.setValue(attributeValue);
  }

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The startelement for you will be chart and in that count will be the attribute and that will come in the if part and than in else if part the Sales_x0020_Amount will come and for that attribute will be Label. refer this [tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/xml/how-to-parse-remote-xml-using-sax-parser-with-android-asynctask/).